# Django generic class-based view example: where does **kwargs come from?

Tags: django

In the examples, I constantly see **kwargs passed around with no mention of where it is coming from:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from books.models import Publisher, Book

class PublisherDetailView(DetailView):

    context_object_name = "publisher"
    model = Publisher

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(PublisherDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.all()
        return context
```

Where is **kwargs being magically plucked from?

Also, does this not seem like a whole lot of extra work just to add a single dictionary object?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1769403/576139

Comment: I'm talking about this specific instance.  I know what **kwargs means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the base implementation of `SingleObjectMixin` (the "original" `get_context_data`).

It simply returns `**kwargs` as the context (a dictionary), while adding the object being edited with the key specified.

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = kwargs
            context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(self.object)
            if context_object_name:
                context[context_object_name] = self.object
            return context
```

In a `DetailView`, the kwargs are "magically plucked" from whatever is calling it / passing in those kwargs. In your case, that would be `BaseDetailView.get()`.

```
class BaseDetailView(SingleObjectMixin, View):
        def get(self, request, **kwargs):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```

It's later used by many view classes (as in `render_to_response(self.get_context_data)`) which passes the raw `context` dictionary to `self.response_class` which is by default `django.template.TemplateResponse`.

`TemplateResponse` knows how to render itself, and in its `resolve_context` function, finally converts the dictionary to a `django.template.Context`

You really can follow the source all the way from the original method all the way down.

Answer (score 5):

The kwargs are generated in the [URLConf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).  For example this will populate the `pk` item:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^authors/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AuthorDetailView.as_view()),
)
```

The call is via the [`view`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L44) function in `View.as_view` and then through `View.dispatch` which calls [`TemplateView.get`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L124).